# Is 'void' a valid return value for a function?

Tags: c#, return, void

```
private void SaveMoney(string id...)
{
    ...
}

public void DoSthWithMoney(string action,string id...)
{
    if(action=="save") return SaveMoney(string id);
    ...
}
```

Why won't C# let me return the void of the private function back through the public function? It even is the same data type "void"...

Or isn't void a data type?

Is the following code really the shortest workaround?

```
if(action=="save") {
    SaveMoney(string id);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043034/what-does-void-mean-in-c-c-and-c

Comment: Literally never considered this, it's a neat idea if you're lazy :D

Comment: void means nothing, so you don't return anything, just use the return statement on its own.

Comment: @Naveen Note that the code here is chaining a return of a function that also returns void, that isn't really a duplicate.

Comment: void is not a data type per se (void* is a different matter). If a function returns a void it means it does not return a value ( the compiler will not take steps to place any value in the registers specified in the calling convention). So what you are trying here is not correct !!!

Comment: I don't see any reason why the compiler couldn't permit this; the compiler knows precisely what is happening here. It seems to just be the case that few would try to do this.

Comment: @nos His question is pointing basically at "what is void", so i added "possible" :).

Comment: @Mr.Smith The compiler *could* know - but it's just a matter of language definition. In a function declared `void` (not *returning* `void` - you can't return a `void`) you may not `return` a value (and if you were able to write it as above, `void` would be considered a value, which it is not).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`void` is *not* an actual return (data)type! `void` says there *is no* result. So you can not return a value in a method that's declared `void` even though the method you're calling is also declared `void`.

I must admit it would be a nice shortcut, but it's not how things work :-)

---

Just an additional thought: If what you want was allowed, `void` would become both a data type *and* also the only possible value of that data type, as `return x;` is defined as returning the value `x` to the caller. So `return void;` would return the value `void` to the caller - not possible by definition.

This is different for `null` for example, as `null` is a valid value for reference types.

Comment: Why/how would `void` have value `void`? If it had nothing in it, wouldn't it be more or less a typeless array of size zero?

Comment: One could argue this is a case of the [Is-ought fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is%E2%80%93ought_problem). C# **could** permit this special-case by rewriting `return SaveMoney(id);` to `{SaveMoney(id);return;}` for you at compile-time. We've seen similar rewrites with `foreach` (when used on arrays), and even some instances of `for`. It just may not be for the better...

Comment: @Alexander This thought was because the method declaration is defined as to declare the *type* being returned (or `void` if there's no return value). `return` is defined to be used standalone without a return value, or to return the *value*. This would make `void` both a type and a value.

Comment: @Mr.Smith Of course this could be done. Calling extension methods is another example for syntactic sugar like that. I'm not saying it can't be done - I'm just saying that the use of the `void` keyword would not be clear anoymore.

Comment: Not really, since I don't write `return void`, but `return someFuncThatReturnsVoid()`, which "returns a value of type void", so to say.

Comment: @Alexander You don't write `return void`, but effectively that's what that call would result in, just like `return Math.Sqrt(4);` effectively results in `return 2.0;` :-) Still, even in your sample, `void` would be a "value of type void", which would make `void` both a type and a value. Again, I'm not saying that this couldn't be handled as a special case in the language definition, but I'm trying to give a possible explanation of why it hasn't been done. I guess it is in the same problem class as `NULL` in SQL :-)

Comment: `Math.Sqrt()`, or let's just name it `someFuncThatReturnsFloat(4)`, returns 2.0, not `float`... and it may be defined that someFuncThatReturnsVoid() returns 42, not `void`. There is no definition that void is a valid value for datatype `void`. While there are always 256 valid values for a `byte`, and 2 valid values for a `bool`, you have two possibilities how many values there are for a `void` - 0 or 1. The space required to save that "value" is the same, whether it can have 0 or 1 different values, entropy is always 0 bits. The difference is that the 0-possible-values void cannot be returned.

Comment: OK, let's agree that `void` doesn't necessarily have to be the value that is actually returned. It could also be a constant named `void.VALUE`. Still, `void` would become a data type. By definition it is not. Let's also agree that one *could* one day implement this as syntactic sugar. Currently this is not the case, so my answer is correct saying that `void` is not a data type and yes, your code is the shortest, while not the only possible solution to the "problem".

Comment: @Alexander: This actually *is* possible in C++/CLI, which also is a .net language. Most probably it was adapted from pure C++. I assume the compiler does exactly what Mr. Smith proposed in his comment, making 2 separate commands out of this single line. I am missing that in C# now, when converting my code from C++/CLI.

Answer (score 6):

`void` is not a type in C#. In this instance, `void` means the [absence of a return type or value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yah0tteb.aspx) so you cannot use it with `return` as you have in the first example.

This is different to C, for example, where void can mean [typeless or an unknown type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400125/when-can-void-be-used-and-what-are-the-advantages-of-doing-so).

Answer (score 4):

That is not a workaround, it is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Even if this would compile I wouldn't recommend it. In such a small method, it's clear what's going on, but if it's a bigger method, the next programmer is going to see that, blink, think "I thought this was a void method" scroll up, confirm that, scroll back down, follow the SaveMoney method, find out it returns nothing, etc.

Your "workaround" makes that clear at a glance.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the method to a boolean and return 0.

Comment: You cannot return `0` for a `bool` function in C#